# How to sort numbers with text numerically in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

My table has alphanumeric values. I'd like to order them numerically first but it cannot work.

Below is example table, table name is called `method_1` :

```html
id  |    code_name | 
4     200 a
1     100 b
3     100-1 c
9     100-1/1 d
11    100-1/1/1 e
12    100-1/1/10 f
2     100-1/1/11 g
13    100-1/1/3 h
14    100-2 i
20    100-1/2 j
32    100-1/2/1 k
```

I am using MYSQL Query Browser version 1.2.11, my SQL query is `SELECT * FROM method_1 order by code_name` , but it cannot sort the number correctly. And I am also using this method `SELECT * FROM method_1 order by length(code_name), code_name`, still cannot work

Actually I want the expected result is like below the table:

```html
id  |    code_name | 
1     100 b
3     100-1 c
9     100-1/1 d
11    100-1/1/1 e
13    100-1/1/3 h
12    100-1/1/10 f
2     100-1/1/11 g
20    100-1/2 j
32    100-1/2/1 k
14    100-2 i
4     200 a
```

**Using jarlh answer**

[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta4Qs.png)

Comment: That will be a lot of work. You have to find and extract each number.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for your answer. But the last digit cannot sort. It will order become 1,10,11,12,2,20,29

Comment: I have updated 1 picture on my question using your method

Comment: Does each part of numeric subcode has some limit? for example, not more than 3 digits for each part, i.e. from 100-1/1/1 to 999-999/999/999? If so then simply normalize the code by leading zeros adding, i.e. 100-1/1/1 => 100-001/001/001, then sort the values as common strings.

Comment: Not more than 3 digits.

Comment: max is 999 digits in my table

Comment: @PiNetworkCrytocurrency, I said _each_ number, i.e. including the last one.

Comment: first number must 999 digis, second until fourth number no limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte AS (SELECT id, 
               code_name,
               CONCAT('[', REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(code_name, ' ', 1), '[\-\/ ]', ','), ']') code,
               SUBSTRING_INDEX(code_name, ' ', -1) name
        FROM test)
SELECT id,
       code_name
FROM cte
ORDER BY code->>"$[0]" + 0,
         code->>"$[1]" + 0,
         code->>"$[2]" + 0,
         code->>"$[3]" + 0,
         name;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=088a0f7b12b65cc3b39b7b7623de0693)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my SQL version cannot support your code.  Got any method can replace?

Comment: @PiNetworkCrytocurrency Do you want us to guess the version of your server?

Comment: My question has mentioned MYSQL Query Browser version 1.2.11

Comment: It is earlier version.

Comment: @PiNetworkCrytocurrency MySQL Query Browser is client software, not MySQL server. We're not interested in its version.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
            ,SUBSTRING(code_name,1,3) AS A1 
            ,SUBSTRING(code_name,4, MAX LEN) AS A2  
      FROM T ) AS T_Total 
ORDER BY T_Total.A1 
        ,T_Total.A2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my SQL version cannot support your code.  Got any method can replace?